# Using class file located in non-root directory with LyX

Tags: lyx, document-classes

I would like to use the template `elsarticle.lyx`, but apparently I'm missing `elsarticle.cls`. Unfortunately I don't have root rights, so I can't follow most instructions on the web on installing new packages. What I did instead was to get the elsarticle package from CTAN, and put it in a directory `~/texmf`. The environment variable `TEXMFHOME` was not defined, so I executed `export TEXMFHOME=$HOME/texmf/`, followed by a call of `texhash`. From what I can tell that worked just fine. Now I reconfigure and restart LyX, but it still complains about the missing `elsarticle.cls` when I try to use the template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution. I noticed that even when not using LyX, but plain LaTeX, the class file was not found. This is because the LaTeX package was expecting it to live in `~/texmf/tex/latex`. Once I moved the `elsarticle` files into that subdirectory, everything fell into place.